# Selecting Range in VBA

Tags: vba, find, range

Currently I have a problem regarding the selection of a range to copy into another worksheet.

The idea of my steps and the current problem is explained in the code:

```
 With .Sheets("worksheet(1)").Select

    ' here I selected the right worksheet to search for the "word1"         
    Variable = Cells.Find(What:="word1").Activate

    'here I searched for the "word1", which is a Header of a long table           
    ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Select

    'I selected the entire Column
     Selection.Copy

    'Now I copy the whole  area

End With
```

The problem is that I want to have not only the entire column, but everything marked for copying until a certain Name `word5` at the end of the table.

Comment: You can do a for loop, finding the coordinate of your last cell, then selecting only this range. There are multiple ways to do it, including built-in functions (to find last row or column at least)

Comment: How to check what’s “marked for copying”?

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid using all these `Select` and `Activate`, instead use fully qualified objects.

Also, using the `Find` function you need to set the result to a `Range` object, and also handle a scenario an error will occur when `Find` is unable to find `"word1"`.

**Code**

```
Dim VariableRng As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("worksheet(1)") '<-- is "worksheet(1)" the name of your worksheet ?
    ' set the range to Find result
    Set VariableRng = .Cells.Find(What:="word1")
    If Not VariableRng Is Nothing Then ' find was successful
        VariableRng.EntireColumn.Copy
    Else ' Find failed >> raise error msgbox
        MsgBox "Can't find 'word1' in " & .name & " sheet"
    End If
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]I think you need to find word5 within the same column to create a limit if you dont to copy the entire column

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim xl_first_range As Range
    Dim xl_second_range As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("worksheet(1)")

    'here I selected the right worksheet to search for the "word1"

    Set xl_first_range = .Cells.Find(What:="word1", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    True, SearchFormat:=False)

    'here I searched for the "word1", which is a Header of a long table and word5 in the same column

    Set xl_second_range = xl_first_range.EntireColumn.Cells.Find(What:="word5", LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    True, SearchFormat:=False)

    'Select the entire Column until word5 cell

    .Range(xl_first_range, xl_second_range).Copy

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: It works perfectly, just had no time to answer, but really big thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you’re after this

```
With .Sheets("worksheet(1)")
    .Range(.Cells.Find(What:="word1"), .Cells.Find(What:="word5").Copy
End With
```

Of course this “With-End With” block must be nested within some outer “With SomeWorkbookReference - End With” outer block. Or you remove the dot before Sheets("worksheet(1)")

Comment: and what happend is there is no `"word1" in the worksheet ?

Comment: @ShaiRado, it errors out, of course. same with “word5”. But I assumed from OP’s question it has to be taken for granted that they are always in place